# Not get Report in Flurry Android Analytics

Tags: android, flurry-analytics

I have integrated Flurry Analytics in my application but unable to get the report on Flurry Dashboard however I integrated it same as mentioned in Flurry ReadMe PDF. I implemented all codes required for that with API Key but doesn't know why I am not receive any report. Please suggest any solution regarding the same. Please look on to the Log below:

Log Detail:

```
10-28 16:50:29.502: I/dalvikvm(21929): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.getId, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dj.v
10-28 16:50:29.502: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9042: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;.getId ()Ljava/lang/String;
10-28 16:50:29.502: D/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0042
10-28 16:50:29.512: I/dalvikvm(21929): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dj.o
10-28 16:50:29.512: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 9043: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;.isLimitAdTrackingEnabled ()Z
10-28 16:50:29.512: D/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
10-28 16:50:29.522: I/dalvikvm(21929): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo, referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.dw.c
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: unable to resolve static method 9044: Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient;.getAdvertisingIdInfo (Landroid/content/Context;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-28 16:50:29.522: D/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x000a
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: unable to resolve exception class 1320 (Lcom/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;)
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY: unable to find exception handler at addr 0x43
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x0d at 0x0043
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): VFY:  rejected Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;.c ()Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient$Info;
10-28 16:50:29.522: W/dalvikvm(21929): Verifier rejected class Lcom/flurry/sdk/dw;
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929): java.lang.VerifyError: com/flurry/sdk/dw
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929):    at com.flurry.sdk.dj$1.a(SourceFile:247)
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929):    at com.flurry.sdk.fc.run(SourceFile:49)
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 16:50:29.532: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-28 16:50:29.542: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
10-28 16:50:29.562: W/FlurryAgent(21929): Start session with context: com.handygo.rockasap.screens.SplashActivity@43046458 count:0
10-28 16:50:30.792: W/System.err(21929): java.io.IOException: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
10-28 16:50:30.802: W/System.err(21929):    at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
10-28 16:50:30.802: W/System.err(21929):    at com.handygo.rockasap.services.SendDeviceInfoTask.doInBackground(SendDeviceInfoTask.java:74)
10-28 16:50:30.812: W/System.err(21929):    at com.handygo.rockasap.services.SendDeviceInfoTask.doInBackground(SendDeviceInfoTask.java:1)
10-28 16:50:30.812: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-28 16:50:30.822: W/System.err(21929):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-28 16:50:30.822: W/System.err(21929):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-28 16:50:30.852: W/System.err(21929):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-28 16:50:30.852: W/System.err(21929):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-28 16:50:30.852: W/System.err(21929):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
10-28 16:50:31.982: D/dalvikvm(21929): threadid=1: still suspended after undo (sc=1 dc=1)
10-28 16:50:31.982: D/dalvikvm(21929): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 993K, 6% free 19368K/20392K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
10-28 16:50:32.942: W/FlurryAgent(21929): FlurryDataSender: report 72374d1e-cb0e-4196-bd5e-349416cb112a sent. HTTP response: 200
```

Code in Splash Screen:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FlurryAgent.onStartSession(this, "Y29JTBGCWHXWGKXN47YS");
        FlurryAgent.setLogEnabled(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogEvents(true);
        FlurryAgent.setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        FlurryAgent.onEndSession(this);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you use Google Play Services?

Comment: are you getting any error in *Flurry* ?? The Exception log will not be reflected immediately ion dashborad. It takes 24-hr time approximately..

Comment: @weston Yeah I already used Google Play Services.

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Exception Log? But I want to see atleast active users on Flurry Dashboard. Is it also will updated after 24hr?

Comment: yes..it will be updated in 24 hr... you have to wait..Any entry on Flurry dashboard takes time :(

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Ok Means I have to wait 24 Hr. again and again for any report (Exceptions, Events Log) in Flurry.

Comment: Yes everytime you need to wait atleast for 12 hr..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63781/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-sanat-pandey).

Comment: @SweetWisherツ Ok Lets See tomorrow for update...Thanks for your valuable comment.

Comment: Did you get Flurry report??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The reflection of your flurry Integration won't be immediate.** You need to keep patience. Approximately it takes 24hr ro reflect changes on Flurry Dashboard. Please check the Flurry Dashboard tomorrow and let me know if you face the same problem.