# Flurry displays nothing in android app

Tags: android, flurry

I was trying to integrate a banner ad to my code.Unfortunately displays nothing.
.
and in console it displays

ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.flurrydemo/.MainActivity }

Can someone help me please?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The reflection of your flurry Integration won't be immediate. You need to keep patience. Approximately it takes 24hr ro reflect changes on Flurry Dashboard. Please check the Flurry Dashboard tomorrow and let me know if you face the same problem.

see this [Flurry 4.2.0 not working for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27143545/flurry-4-2-0-not-working-for-android)
and this [Not get Report in Flurry Android Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26607172/not-get-report-in-flurry-android-analytics)

Comment: Thanks.It displays the following message in my console 16:08:39.034: E/FlurryAgent(1953): Ad server responded but sent no ad units.

Answer (score 0):

Please, don't publish your API_KEY as someone else could steal it from you. No data will be get if someone didi it, but someone could make your analytics data show fake events.

You are using the deprecated way of integrating with Flurry Ads. See http://flurrydev.github.io/FlurryAndroidSDK5xAPI/classcom_1_1flurry_1_1android_1_1ads_1_1FlurryAdBanner.html#a09fb49838048b0027db636ca56d8e550

From your code, it seems it is not needed any condition to show the ad, so just use FlurryAdsBanner.fetchAndDisplay.

And, as @survivor said, it takes some time to start sending you ads back. Enabling test mode would accelerate this. This can be achieved by adding your device ID on the field for the ad space. Device ID is the one which is shown on Google Settings/Ads, the one which allows advertising SDKs to see if user has opt-out.